# Android: layout -> button selector -> button not getting smaller

Tags: android, button, size, selector

So I have this problem. I made a button and a .xml button selector file and everything is fine except one thing.

**What I want to happen:** when you click (or select) the button, the button gets smaller (it changes to a smaller .png file, to be accurate).

**What's happening:** when you click (or select) the button, the button doesn't get smaller, it gets streched out to fit parent (all in all, size keeps the same). I'm thinking that it has something to do with the wrong layout parameters. Could you help me out? Here's some code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/listbg"
    android:paddingTop="110dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Button1" 
            android:background="@drawable/placestovisit"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <!-- This is the button I am talking about -->
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Button2" 
            android:background="@drawable/mostpopular_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to all your buttons:

```
     android:onClick="doButtonAction"
```

Do this in your activity for the button layout

```
public void doButtonAction(View view)
{
   Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(view.getId());
   yourButton.setScaleX(.8);
   yourButton.setScaleY(.8);
   //do button stuff here
}
```

If that doesn't work by itself, maybe try setting the height and width of the button explicitly such as:

```
     android:layout_height="50px"
     android:layout_width="150px"
```

It might be the case that avoiding using Wrap Content will prevent the stretching.